# android Broadcast Receiver not works

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I programming with android studio and I want to have a Broadcast receiver to do something every time the time of clock change (it means every single minute that for example the time of phone changed from `3:13` to `3:14`) even if the program isn't run. so I should use a Broadcast receiver with `Time_Tick` Action. But It just work when the Activity created. any Idea?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    BroadcastReceiver br;
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter i=new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction("android.intent.action.TIME_TICK");
        registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(),i);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MyReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
        Log.i("Saaalam","saaaalaalam");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.etsiamak.broadcastrecierver" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"></action> </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ref  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

Comment: Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Comment: @arun how I should Register?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code for time tick. The TIME_TICK intent gets fired minute change.

static TimeReceiver tickReceiver = new TimeReceiver();

```
void setTimeTick()
{
     registerReceiver(tickReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    "android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"));
     Toast.makeText(this, "Registered broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

     //Register the broadcast receiver to receive TIME_TICK
     registerReceiver(tickReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));    
}
```

The Reciever Class

```
class TimeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {     
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "Time tick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this code into Manifest

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you need to execute certain task after certain amount of time say one minutes. For this you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

```
AlarmManager myAlarmManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)
```

Example for AlarmManager: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/scheduling-an-application-to-start-later/

Or Android introduced the [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/samples/JobScheduler/index.html) API in Android 5.0 (API 21). It is better then AlarmManager as it does not consider if the device is connected to a power plug, idle or connected.

Example for JobScheduler: [how-to-use-androids-job-scheduler](http://toastdroid.com/2015/02/21/how-to-use-androids-job-scheduler/)